# How to differentiate Coded UI and Screen reader?

Tags: wpf, coded-ui-tests, screen-readers, automationpeer

we have override the `OnCreateAutomationPeer` for implementing the Coded UI. The same `OnCreateAutomationPeer` is called for Screen reader also(ex. Narrator tool default screen reader tool from windows).

Is there any possibility to differentiate the `OnCreateAutomationPeer` is triggered from screen reader or Coded UI?